# Use Visual Studio solution in ci server or maintain a separate build file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, continuous-integration, nant

What is common way of doing this?

Maintaining a separate build file (nant by example) costs time but Will not lock you in to Visual studio.

Do most developers build with the Visual studio solution or do they have to use the nant build file.

What are the best practices?

Answer (score 1):

What I do is use the proj files rather than sln files. MSbuild processes them just fine.

This way you have the best of both worlds. You are not locked into VS, but you do not have to maintain 2 copies of your build files either

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your project...

I have multiple solutions that i want to build as one product, so i use msbuild / nant to include them all.

Another reason to use a build file is when you have more actions you want to execute when the CI server builds the project and you don't want those actions to be executed when the developers build the solution (Copying files for deployment or setting assembly version for example)

In general, i think that unless you have a reason to use a build file, you can just use the sln file

Comment: .sln files are not MSBuild files, .*proj files are, but u can pass the .sln file to MSBuild.exe.